# JTAG + openocd + kernel debugging (no debug information in vmlinux ?)

Tags: kernel, jtag, openocd

When I connect to target from eclipse I get the message:

```
symbol-file /opt/Tixi_Repos/KiwiG6v2/buildroot-2011.05/package_tixi/linux-2.6.39/arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux
target remote localhost:3333
start () at arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S:108
108         kphex   r5, 8       /* end of kernel */
```

But afterwards when I stop the running kernel:
 0xc06f2674
No source available for ""

Also when I try to step:
target request failed: Cannot find bounds of current function.

It seems that there are no symbols in vmlinux. But kernel is rebuild with both DEBUG_KERNEL and DEBUG_INFO are set.

kernel 2.6.39
CPU AT91SAM9G25

```
openocd -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/interface/jtagkey2.cfg -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/board/at91sam9g20-ek.cfg


TapName            | Enabled |   IdCode      Expected    IrLen IrCap  IrMask   Instr     
---|--------------------|---------|------------|------------|------|------|------|---------
 0 | at91sam9g20.cpu    |    Y    | 0x00000000 | 0x0792603f | 0x04 | 0x01 | 0x0f | 0x0f
Info : max TCK change to: 30000 kHz
Info : RCLK (adaptive clock speed)
Info : JTAG tap: at91sam9g20.cpu tap/device found: 0x0792603f (mfg: 0x01f, part:0x7926, ver: 0x0)
Info : Embedded ICE version 6
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection from 0
Warn : acknowledgment received, but no packet pending
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 differend vmlinux files are compiled in my system: one in root folder and the second one in arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155885/two-differend-vmlinux-files